# Is it possible to open a .exe in windows 7 and assign it a user defined process id?

Tags: windows-7, process

i need to update a file that a game server uses for some research i am doing. Changing this file means i need to restart the server which is only possible by ending the process and restarting it. Is it possible to start this .exe with the same process id?

Comment: I'm curious as to why someone has voted to close as off-topic. Seems pretty on-topic to me.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible.  You'll have to find a way to get the new process ID into any lists which hold out-of-date references.

You can see why it can't be possible by reading the documentation for the [`PROCESS_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684873.aspx) structure returned by `CreateProcess()`:

> A value that can be used to identify a
>   process. The value is valid from the
>   time the process is created until all
>   handles to the process are closed and
>   the process object is freed; **at this
>   point, the identifier may be reused**.  (emphasis mine)

Since these IDs can be reused, there's no guarantee that the system won't have re-used it.